# Extract String From Text (Word)

Tags: vba

I need to find a specific string of text from a large source of material. I've just used Excel VBA up to this point, so I don't know the Word objects and I ended up just recording some macros and working with what I had. However, this way is very inefficient. I looked on Stack Overflow, but I didn't understand what they were doing, so I just did it this way.

What I am mostly looking for is the objects used in Word VBA that are equivalent to the Excel 'Range', 'Cells', 'Row', and 'Column'.  I looked on MSDN, but there is so much material there that you need to have an idea of what you are looking for, and I couldn't find any other sites that would help.

This is what I wrote, and it did the job, but it is very inefficient.

```
Sub FindMediaInBraces()

    ' Separate needed text
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[Media"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p^p[Media"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ".jpg]"
        .Replacement.Text = ".jpg]^p^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ".png]"
        .Replacement.Text = ".png]^p^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    ' Remove text that doesn't start correctly
    Dim i As Long

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.count
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        With Selection.Find
            .Execute FindText:="[Media"
            .Forward = True
            If .Found = True Then
                Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, count:=1
            Else
                Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

### Example Text

Original

```
Type: MC
Objectives: 2.6
16) [HTML]If <i>y</i> varies directly with <i>x</i>, write an equation for the direct variation. Then find the value. If <i>y</i> = -4 when <i>x</i> = -28, what is the value of <i>x</i> when <i>y</i> = 5?[/HTML]
*a. `$y=\frac{1}{7}x;\,\, 35$`
b. `$y=-\frac{1}{7}x;\,\, -35$`
c. `$y=7x;\,\, \frac{5}{7}$`
d. `$y=-7x;\,\, -\frac{5}{7}$`

Type: MC
Objectives: 3.3
21) Select the graph that correctly represents the following system of equations: 
  `$y=-\frac{5}{3}x+3$`
  `$y=\frac{1}{3}x-3$`
*a. [Media:Media/Images/Problem 21a.jpg]
b. [Media:Media/Images/Problem 21b.jpg]
c. [Media:Media/Images/Problem 21c.jpg]
d. [Media:Media/Images/Problem 21d.jpg]
```

After Macro

```
[Media:Media/Images/Problem 21a.jpg]
[Media:Media/Images/Problem 21b.jpg]
[Media:Media/Images/Problem 21c.jpg]
[Media:Media/Images/Problem 21d.jpg]
```

---

This is what I found on Stack Overflow, but I don't know the objects to use to apply it, and I don't know if it would actually work in this case.

```
dim str as string
dim openPos as integer
dim closePos as integer
dim midBit as string

str = "NUMBER(8,3)"
openPos = instr (str, "(")
closePos = instr (str, ")")
midBit = mid (str, openPos+1, closePos - openPos - 1)
```

Comment: [word object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837519.aspx) - paragraph, page etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to do this would be by [`.Sentences`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837481.aspx), assuming your string doesn't appear more than once per sentence. You can use `instr` to get the location of your strings and then store them in an array. Then print them wherever you want:

```
Sub GetMediaStrings()
    Const BEGIN_STRING As String = "[Media:"
    Const END_STRING As String = ".jpg"
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim startString As Long
    Dim endString As Long
    Dim results() As String
    ReDim results(1 To 2)
    For Each searchRange In ActiveDocument.Sentences
        startString = InStr(1, searchRange, BEGIN_STRING, vbTextCompare)
        If startString > 0 Then
            endString = InStr(1, searchRange, END_STRING, vbTextCompare)
            If endString > 0 Then
                results(UBound(results) - 1) = Mid(searchRange, startString, endString - startString + Len(END_STRING))
                ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(results) + 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You might also want to do it via [`.StoryRanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845743.aspx).